# Would moving a mailbox to its own database improve performance?

Tags: exchange-2010

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/568008/10842) suggests moving a large mailbox (50 gb) to a new Exchange database. Will that improve performance, such as moving mail from one folder to another and will it improve search speed?

Comment: You ought to start by trying to narrow down the source of the performance problem. Don't randomly make changes in the hopes that they'll fix your problem. What does `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus` say about the Content Index state? What are the results of `Test-ExchangeSearch`? Have you run a performance baseline check with the BPA?

Comment: @joeqwerty CopyQueue length = 0, ReplayLength = 0, SearchTime in Seconds = 2,355

Comment: Is the search time 2,355 as in two thousand three hundred fifty five?

Comment: I think it is 2 seconds .355.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a large mailbox to a different database will only increase performance if the destination database exists on either a different server, or different disk to the source database.

In virtualized environments connected to a SAN, sometimes moving the mailboxes to a database that resides on a different disk may not have a performance benefit because the data may exist on the same physical disk in the storage array.
To get around this, you might consider creating an exchange database on a disk that exists on a different SCSI bus, or a different LUN.